# Java deserialise json to implementation of abstract object open closed principle

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have polymorphic types of Varchar, Integer and Float that extend a base class.

I have had to add the following to the base class so I can use it in a rest api.

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "VarcharField", value = VarcharField.class),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "IntegerField", value = IntegerField.class),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "FloatField", value = FloatField.class)
})
public abstract class Field<T> implements FieldType<T>, Serializable {
```

My issue with this is that it breaks the open closed principle, is there anyway to get around this, an external config perhaps?

Comment: Explain how open-closed principle is broken. I'm not saying it isn't, I just want to know what your problem is. If you just don't want to enumerate all the subclasses, then use `JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS` or `JsonTypeInfo.Id.MINIMAL_CLASS`.

Comment: Every time that I need to add a new field I will have to modify the abstract class, albeit very slightly, I feel the class should be closed for any modification, this feels like configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If use `JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS` or `JsonTypeInfo.Id.MINIMAL_CLASS`, you will not need to specify subtypes.